# Poor performance when changing tint color of imageView

Tags: swift, image, performance, tintcolor

I have the following line of code:

```
imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

This line takes a relatively long time to execute(In the simulator it takes about .35s versus the .20s it takes to load the entire rest of my interface). The view needs to load as fast as possible so although .35s may not seem like a lot it is important. The image in the image view is a simple template image. How can I go about improving the performance of this?

The only thing I can thing of would be to draw the simple image from scratch using core graphics but that seems like a complex answer to a simple problem. Any ideas?

Note: This image tint is changed several times throughout the time the app is alive.

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the tint command on the main thread?

Comment: How are you measuring this?

Comment: Using the main thread solved the issue, Josh at The Nerdery

Comment: I am comparing the date before and after the code is ran

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not specifically running the code on the main queue. This massively sped up the code.